# Обновление геолокации

Tags: objective-c

Приветствую, сразу прошу прощения за ошибки или не очень правильно поставленный вопрос. И так вопрос заключается в том, что для того чтобы мне получить данные о геолокации нужно прождать около 0,5 - 1 сек.
Стоит ли использовать код ниже или как будет правильно сделать ? Или стоит поставить как-то условие на получение данных. (пока не получили данные, не выполнять следующий код..) Совсем запутался...

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ 
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f]; 
    });
```

[image: Время вызова функций]

Comment: вам надо не остановить все приложение на два секунды, а начать выполнять локацию через две секунды. посмотрите performSelector:afterDelay https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector?language=objc

Comment: Спасибо @MaxMikheyenko кстати за прошлый вопрос с широтой и долготой, видел у вас получилось добавить новую ветку в мое приложение. Так если я запущу локацию через две секунды метод который обновляет данные на экране получит пустые значения. Получается как. Запуск приложения 1 Метод идет запуск геолокации потом получение данных с сервера потом обновление лэйбблов на экране. Но только после вызова метода обновления лэйблов приходит геолокация по сути с опозданием и уже не нужная. Коряво написал конечно...

Comment: то есть, вам надо после обновления локации сделать что то еще? тогда просто весь код, который должен выполниться вызывайте из `didUpdateLocation` или как он там называется

Answer (score 1):

если хотите, чтобы каждый определенный интервал времени у вас вызывался метод с обновлением геолокации - используйте NSTimer.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer